# Trying to get at why singletons are considered a bad thing; why is aggregation better?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, global

I'm trying to understand why Singletons are frowned upon.

Let's say I have singleton MyClass:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void doSomething();
    static MyClass* getInstance();
private:
    int whatever;
    static MyClass* myClass;
    MyClass();
};
```

I have a class that references it:

```
void A::B()
{
    ...
    MyClass::getInstance()->doSomething();
}
```

What I've read is that now class A is dependant on MyClass. Testing class A effectively means testing MyClass at the same time. Anybody anywhere can be modifying our MyClass at the same time, so the result of A::B() is unpredictable.

But why is the global accessibility the cause of this? What if we had aggregation instead? What if class A had a pointer or reference to our MyClass object, and other classes also had pointers or references to that same object?

```
class A
{
public:
    void B();
private:
    MyClass* myClass;
};
void A::B()
{
    ...
    myClass->doSomething();
}
```

Couldn't you have the same problem, whereby some other class is modifying the same myClass object at the same time, and therefore A::B() is dependant on that? I guess the question is, isn't it almost like "global state" to have a reference to the same thing in multiple locations?

(I recognize this question has been posted before, but I don't think anyone else has specifically asked about why multiple references to the same object is any better.)

Answer (score 1):

**"Anybody anywhere can be modifying our MyClass at the same time"**

That is only possible in some sort of multi-threaded or multi process environment. Your second example would seem to be no better if that is the concern.

Globals - or Singletons as your calling them - are not recommended in multi-threaded environments because of potential concurrent access, which is what you're talking about. To avoid concurrency problems, you will need to deal with synchronization mechanisms - not always so easy.

Even without multi threading, Globals tend to make code difficult to manage, debug and control in anything more than trivial systems.

Generally "aggregation" is not an alternative to "singleton". The alternative to singleton is multiple instances, each dedicated to a particular thread, or local to a particular class or method - perhaps what you mean by "aggregation" - thereby avoiding concurrency and control/code management issues.

"**aggregation**" **"delegation"** or **"object composition"** (more or less synonymous terms in this context) are generally considered the alternative to **inheritance**: rather than inheriting functionality from a base class, it is often more desirable to design a completely separate class that performs the necessary functionality and is referenced and controlled by the calling class - the "Black Box" concept.

Among the problems with inheritance is that it tends to force derived classes to deal with implementation and behavior from a base class that may be inappropriate in the derived class. Invariably it also forces exposure of implementation details to derived classes, thereby violating encapsulation. Ideally, a well designed class hierarchy will avoid this problem, but designing such a class hierarchy is generally no simple matter if you're dealing with anything outside the textbook definition of class Cat(Animal), class Dog (Animal) etc.

Comment: "Singletons ... are not recommended in multi-threaded environments".  What if your singleton is just used to read a config file and its state meant to be exactly the same from startup for all threads (or web requests from any and all clients for example.  The name of the application for example.)?  I'm not an expert on this matter, just curious about such a scenario.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer - Assuming that the file system is configured to allow concurrent reads (and READS ONLY), reading a static file should not be a problem.

Comment: @Mikey - I think when I was using the word "aggregation", I sort of meant it in contrast to "containment". I was envisioning a scenario of multiple objects referencing a single object. It seems like when multiple objects can reference a single object, you may have many of the dangers of "global accessibility". Although, I suppose in this case you've at least granted a copy of the reference to each of these objects, which is a way of saying "I trust you", in contrast with global accessibility in which anyone can modify.

Comment: You know, taking another look at definitions, I probably do mean something closer to "association" than "aggregation" - in any case a "has-a" relationship in which other objects also have "association" to the same object...

Comment: @user1832311 -  "granted a copy of the reference to each of these objects, which is a way of saying "I trust you" . Since it's a reference, I think it's more of an invitation for trouble - a reference is just a indirect access to the object - that can obfuscate things.

Comment: @user1832311-IMO globals/singletons should be avoided almost entirely in a well designed system running on modern hardware. What do you gain with globals? Save resources? Factory Methods, lean, well designed classes and functions, and being aware that by "byte squeezing doesn't pay" in modern computing environments, should allow you to avoid ever using globals. If you do use them it should only be in situations where access is necessary only for a very short time, and protecting them is easy. If we're talking about small, embedded systems where resources are critical, that might be different.